# Angular.js animation, combining css and js

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, animation, css-transitions

What I'm trying to do is fadeout old view and fadein new view, the thing is, new content needs to be absolute position until the old one fades out, and I would like to give it some top and maybe height as well, but when I use any `css()` function inside `enter` it seems to be overridden by stuff added by angular(`-webkit-transition-property: opacity, clip; -webkit-transition-duration: 300ms, 300ms;`).

Is this an expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed in this commit and landed in 1.2.2

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/c42d0a041890b39fc98afd357ec1307a3a36208d